# Python-Numpy: Convolution, Code optimization

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

in the python code I'm currently developing there is a particular function that really requires a speed optimization.
To a first approximation I would like to focus on pure python code (no C or Cython implementations).
The function generates a series of gaussian curves with varying sigma depending on the x-axis position. It takes three arguments:

1. x0, 1d numpy array, central values of the gaussian curves
2. h , 1d numpy array, heights of the gaussian curves
3. x , 1d numpy array, values for the definition of the total sum

My goal is to obtain the sum of all the curves in the fastest way possible (it is a sort of convolution with a gaussian curve that has a position dependent sigma).

At the moment my code is:

```
sigs = get_sigmas(x0)  # function that returns the value of sigma at each position

all_gauss_args = -0.5*np.power((x[:, np.newaxis] - x0[np.newaxis, :]) /
                 sigs[np.newaxis, :], 2.0)

sum = (1.0/(np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * sigs[np.newaxis, :])) * np.exp(all_gauss_arg) *\
             h[np.newaxis, :]

sum = np.sum(sum, axis=1)
return sum
```

It is possible to make it faster?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Try to inline `np.power((x[:, np.newaxis] - x0[np.newaxis, :]) / sigs[np.newaxis, :], 2.0)`, i.e. instead of doing `np.power(x,2)` write `x*x`, it should run faster.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm still quite far from the speed I would like to achieve but I had a slight speed improvement thanks to this modification of the code. I'm surrendering to the idea of using Cython or C++ in order to have a significant speed improvement (even if, as far as I know, numpy is already using a lot of Cython.. I don't know how much better I can get)